# Some sounds won't play in IE or Chrome with Creative sound card

Tags: windows, google-chrome, audio, internet-explorer, creative

Chrome and Internet Explorer don't seem to be able to play sounds in some contexts. However, the problem doesn't happen in Firefox. I haven't noticed any other sound-related problems with the computer.

#### Examples of when sound doesn't work

- [The Google Translate page](http://translate.google.com/#fa/en/%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85) (You can click on the speaker icon to pronounce the result.)
- The big play button on [this page](http://www.persianlanguageonline.com/choose-your-level/absolute-beginner/hello/)

#### Examples of when sound works

- YouTube (which is using Flash)
- Using the HTML5 audio API ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/NVJLH/))
- HTML5 audio element ([example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all))

#### What I've Tried

- Upgrading to the latest stable version of Chrome
- Checking Windows' sound mixer to confirm that the applications' audio is not muted or too low
- Disabling and enabling related plugins, including Windows Media Player, Adobe Flash Player, Shockwave Flash and Widevine Content Decryption Module
- Looking at other questions related to Chrome sound problems here, and they seem to be problems with Flash Player or Windows sound mixer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that this problem was caused by the *Creative Audio Service* service not running. Changing it to start automatically resolved the problem:

[image: Services window showing Creative Audio Service running and with Automatic startup]